# pop up message and response.redirect query

Tags: c#, asp.net

what about this one? it seems like its not reading the else part?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["IslandGasAdminPM"] != null)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                bindgrid();
                Label1.Text = "- Purchasing Manager";

            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Purchasing Manager credentials needed'); window.location.href='/LogIn.aspx';</script>");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["IslandGasAdminPM"] != null)
    {
        Label1.Text = "- Purchasing Manager";
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Purchasing Manager credentials needed'); window.location.href='/LogIn.aspx';</script>");
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend using something like the URLHelper class to create the URL instead of hardcoding it.